# How to retrieve all rows from an SQL table into an array?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am trying to retrieve 4 rows and I expected that It should display all 4 rows but it's only displaying the first row. This is the code I am using

```
$coquery = "Select distinct coName from avgcarcompany";
$crun = mysqli_query($con,$coquery);

$arrey = mysqli_fetch_assoc($crun);

print_r($arrey);
```

Comment: What are the values of coName in your database?

Comment: Why do you expect four rows when you fetch only one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get all rows from the result set then you need to fetch all. Right now you are fetching only one.

To fetch all rows use `fetch_all()`

```
$coquery = "Select distinct coName from avgcarcompany";
$crun = $con->query($coquery);

$arrey = $crun->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)

print_r($arrey);
```