# Multiple PDF files with mpdf is return me only one value in all generated files

Tags: php, mysqli, mpdf

I have a MySQL database wirh orders records and I want to generate PDF if status order is payed from all id's and I'm trying with mpdf but is generate me the files but all with the same value.

```
$qry = mysqli_query($dbs, "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE orderstatus='payed'");
$row = array();
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($qry)) {
    $row[] = $data;

    foreach ($row as $x) {
        $folder = 'facturi' . "/" . $x[0];
        if (!is_dir($folder)) {
            mkdir($folder, 0777, true);
            $file_name = "#DPL-" . $x[0] . ".pdf";
            $mpdf->WriteHTML($x[0]); // x[0] is > id, just for testing
        }
    }

    $mpdf->Output($folder . "/" . $file_name, 'F');
}
```

Comment: Do you see the typo after I have formatted your code? You have a loop inside a loop. You can actually avoid the first loop if you use [`mysqli_fetch_all()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)

Comment: Thank you @Dharman for your reply, can you show me how to fetch all ? Im new to this and im doing my best, thank you in advance.

Comment: This can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/62734982/1839439 and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62100343/how-to-retrieve-all-rows-from-an-sql-table-into-an-array/62101059#62101059 and also this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60564642/1839439